# Facebook Logout button not showing

Tags: facebook

I am using Facebook Javascript API on one of my websites and is displaying login button using the following code :

```
<div class = 'connect_fb'>
        <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
 </div>
```

It was working fine until today. But now I have observed some changes.

1. The login button became small as compared to the older one.
2. The login box it is showing is different.
3. There is no logout option after logging in using Facebook.
4. Immediately after logged out, it is not showing the login button again and the Facebook session still exist. Until today , it will logout the user from Facebook System and login button is showed up.

Anyone is experiencing such an issue..? Is there any possibility that the XFBML I have used has been deprecated ..?

You can see the issue here in my website.

http://bit.ly/H1hAZE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far i can remember they deprecated the xFBML tag for login & logout , have a look here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/