# lost facebook logout button while testing on device

Tags: facebook

Any one have an experience on testing an application which is link with facebook.My logout disappear while testing on the device.But in simulator everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're already logged out on your phone which is resulting in the logout button to disappear. Do you have a login button? Is it generating a login\logout url? Do some simple debug to see if you're "logged in" or "logged out".

If you're using the xfmbl tag for login and logout it has been depreciated.

Possibly duplicate of [Facebook Logout button not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594617/facebook-logout-button-not-showing)

It may also be a case sensitivity issue on the file names for the images or a different format that the phone doesn't support.

Check: [Images showing in simulator but not on the iPhone device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485790/images-showing-in-simulator-but-not-on-the-iphone-device)

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485790/images-showing-in-simulator-but-not-on-the-iphone-device